# What's a good way to find out why android is killing my service?

Tags: android, service

I have a long running service (it is intended to run overnight while the phone is charging and has wifi available) and it works fine for a number of hours, then I find myself getting an ondestroy call, and since I started my service as sticky, it immediately starts itself back up.
Presumably because the service starts right away, whatever memory/resources were freed by killing my service solved the problem.

I've added a call to Debug.dumpHprofData in the ondestroy() call, but there's almost nothing in the resulting heapdump.
I mean it's 380k, but that doesn't seem like a lot on a machine with megs of memory.
Okay, maybe lots of cleaning has already been done before ondestroy has been called.

So basically I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing that's causing android to kill my service. Is there a better place to take a heapdump? Are there other resources I may be consuming that's triggering the ending of my service?

There's nothing else on the machine, it's a fresh reset, with this one app installed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you are on charge anyway, can you use the command shell on your development machine to pipe adb logcat into a file overnight, and then examine that?

Comment: good idea there. Hadn't thought of that. thanks